# What does "of or" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

*Of or* pertaining to important records or archives.

Comment: Not a sentence: a phrase. "**of** important records or archives, or **pertaining to** important records and archives". A condensed way of stating the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Of or" is not a constituent.  "Or" is a conjunction which connects the preposition "of" and the preposition "pertaining to" to make the conjoined preposition "of or pertaining to", which then combines with the noun phrase "important records or archives", which is the object of this preposition.  (The latter noun phrase is formed in a corresponding way by using "or" to connect two nouns to make a new noun, "records or archives", which is modified by "important".)

The interpretation is that of "or" connecting the two prepositional phrases which have these prepositions with the prepositional object "important records or archives", and that interpretation is: "of important records or archives or pertaining to important records or archives".

I'm not sure that "pertaining to" should really count as a preposition.  Note that though "or" is called a conjunction here, a logician would prefer the term disjunction.